# Are these versions of the Taylor Theorem equivalent?

Tags: calculus, analysis

In the wikipedia we have this version the Taylor's theorem:

> *Taylor's theorem ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable))*: Let $k\ge 1$ be an integer and let the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be $k$ times
>   differentiable at the point $a \in R$. Then there exists a function
>   $h_k:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that
>
> $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)\cdot (x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}\cdot(x-a)^2\ldots+\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}\cdot (x-a)^k+h_k(x)(x-a)^k,$
>
> where $\lim_{x\to a}h_k(x)=0$.

I'm reading a book which has this another formulation of basically the same theorem:

> *Infinitesimal Taylor Formula*: Let $f:I\to \mathbb R$ be a n times derivable function at the point $a\in I$. Thus, if for every $h$ such
>   that $a+h\in I$, then
>
> $$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)\cdot h+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}\cdot
>  h^2\ldots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\cdot h^n+r(h),$$
>
> where $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{r(h)}{h^n}=0$.

I think this book is wrong, because when we replace $x$ by $a+h$ in the Wikipedia article we should have $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{r(a+h)}{h^n}=0$ instead of $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{r(h)}{h^n}=0$.

Comment: Both are same and it's just a matter of notation.

Comment: No, both are the same. You have $r(h) = h_k(a+h)h^k$.

Answer (score 3):

With the equality $h=x-a$,
$$r(h) = h_k(x) (x-a)^k$$
$$\frac{r(h)}{h^n} = h_k(x)$$
so the limit conditions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are right that replacing $x$ with $a+h$ in the first formula gives a final term of $h_k(a+h)h^k$, and we know the ratio of this quantity to $h^k$ must vanish as $a+h\to a$, i.e. as $h\to0$.

The second formula just views the quantity $h_k(a+h)h^k$ as a function of $h$, since $a$ is typically fixed. But it doesn't matter what you call the final term. You could simply call it $R$. Or you could call it "the difference between $f(x)$ and the $k$-th order approximation centered at $f(a)$." The substance of the claim is that, whatever you call it, its ratio to $(x-a)^k=h^k$ vanishes in the limit.